# Exibir uma imagem que esta fora do projeto JSF

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Olá tenho uma tela que faz um upload de um arquivo e salva em uma pasta em um diretorio do computador até e salva no banco o caminho completo da imagem, agora quero exibir essa imagem em uma tabela por exemplo fiz o exemplo do primefaces porem nao conisgo exibir a imagem.

```
<p:column headerText="Foto">
     <p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox" id="lighbox1">  
          <h:outputLink value="#{item.imagem}" title="Nature 1">  
           <h:graphicImage name="#{salaBean.exibirImagem(item)}" id="nature1" style="height: 77px; width: 100px" />  
           </h:outputLink>
       </p:lightBox>
 </p:column>
```

no meu bean eu trago o caminho completo exemplo:
D:\dados\sar\uploads\Chrysanthemum.jpg

Comment: Porquê usar o `p:lightBox`? Tenta sem ele, e vê no que dá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um StreamedContent para trafegar sua foto.

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{fotoMB.foto}" cache="disable"/>
```

```java
public StreamedContent getFoto(){
    File foto=new File("suafoto.jpg");
    DefaultStreamedContent content=null;
    try{
        BufferedInputStream in=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(foto));
        byte[] bytes=new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();
        content=new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes),"image/jpeg");
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: quem é fotoPerfil

Comment: Falha na hora de simplificar o código para postagem. Corrigido!

Comment: @NilsonUehara, pela minha experiência usando o `StreamedContent` dentro da tabela não funciona.

Comment: @Cold funciona sim, tenho isso em datatable e picklist. Acho que sem a propriedade cache="disable" talvez dê errado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Esse caminho `D:\dados\sar\uploads\` precisa ser servido por um Servlet, ou seja, se eu acessar `http://localhost:8080/app/uploads`, deverá ter esse diretório mapeado.

Após request do browser, ler o caminho do disco e retornar no `response.getOutputStream()`, sem esquecer de settar o Content-Type para `image\jpeg`.

Para ler imagem do disco use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) ou [Apache Commons-IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Comment: Olá Giuliano eu fiz assim

Comment: File file = new File("D:\\dados\\sar\\uploads\\");
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        StreamedContent content = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream, "image/jpeg", "Chrysanthemum.jpg");

Comment: mas ta dando acesso negado

Comment: SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/restrito/sistema/sala.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /restrito/sistema/sala.xhtml @97,157 name="#{salaBean.exibirImagem(item)}": java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\dados\sar\uploads (Acesso negado)

Comment: Pelo que entendi, `uploads` é um diretório, certo? Então deve concatenar algum parâmetro passado pela URL que forme o nome de um arquivo válido, por exemplo o que você citou **Chrysanthemum.jpg**, então você leria de `D:\dados\sar\uploads\Chrysanthemum.jpg`. Se o erro persistir, verifique se tens acesso a esse diretório.