# Consigo pegar uma imagem de qualquer diretório do meu PC, para colocar na minha página HTML?

Tags: java, html, jsf

Consigo pegar uma imagem de qualquer diretório do meu pc, ou eu só consigo pegar imagens apenas do diretório do projeto?
Estou usando JSF:

```
h:graphicImage url="C:\teste\rcvp\18\04\20\16\372_180420160013_0000000_1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Caso haja alguma duvida na resposta abaixo avise.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exibir uma imagem que esta fora do projeto JSF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34043/exibir-uma-imagem-que-esta-fora-do-projeto-jsf)

Comment: Mas, por exemplo, eu posso fazer isso no d:\\, sendo que meu projeto está no c:\\?

Comment: Mas, por exemplo, eu posso fazer isso no d:\\, sendo que meu projeto está no c:\\?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consegue sim! Só que se quiser colocar o site na nuvem ninguém vai conseguir ver.

'O indicado é: coloque tudo em uma pasta, dentro dela, ponha seu index.html, depois crie uma pasta para o css, uma para imagens e assim por diante...

Comment: Acredito que colocando o projeto em web ou então localhost para testar a disposição das pastas seja melhor e mais promissor, procure também algum artigo de boas praticas de indexalização de arquivos e pastas para web